# How current is induced when there is a change in external magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, electromagnetic-induction

If still charges in a wire loop do not respond to a(or have their own) magnetic field, then how is current is generated by changing a magnetic field?  And why only a changing magnetic field? What actually happens at the atomic level?

[image]

Comment: Would you also ask how a current in a wire produces a magnetic field around it, or do you consider that this is less in need of an explanation than a changing magnetic field producing a current (in a closed conducting loop)? Just wondering.

Comment: No, I'm assuming that it is fundamental that when charges move, it produce a magnetic field around them, like poles repels, like opposite charges attracts and like gravitational force

Comment: That's interesting. I see both – the induction of an emf in a stationary circuit (or in Thomas Fritsch's excellent phrase 'a curling electric field')  by a changing magnetic field and the production of a magnetic field around a current (or around a changing electric field) – as equally fundamental. As far as I know, neither can be deduced from the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If still charges in a wire loop do not respond to a (or have their own) magnetic field,…

Electrons at rest (even in a wire loop) have their own magnetic field. Each electron is also a magnetic dipole. Unfortunately, this is often forgotten. Incidentally, this magnetic dipole is even a constant and therefore an intrinsic (unchangeable under all circumstances) property of the electron. Just between us, the electron should actually be called an “electron-magneton”.

> …then how is current is generated by changing a magnetic field?

In electrostatics, electric fields are not influenced by magnetic fields and vice versa. This allows the assumption that the changing external magnetic field affects the magnetic dipoles of the electrons in the conductor loop.

> And why only a changing magnetic field?

While a constant magnetic field only aligns these dipoles in its direction and shifts them sideways as with the Lorentz force, this process is repeated again and again with a changing magnetic field - a current flows.

> What actually happens at the atomic level?

See the explanation above.

Comment: Is that so. I think there are many factors to consider, I need to learn more about it. Thats why I love physics

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to explain 'how', because Faraday's law of induction is a fundamental law of Physics, and asking 'how' is asking why there is such a law.  There just is.

It's not actually current that's induced.  A changing magnetic field induces an electromotive force (i.e. voltage) in the wire loop according the equation
$$\mathcal{E} = -\frac{d\Phi}{dt}$$
where $\Phi$ is the magentic flux through the area of the wire loop.  The minus sign indicates that the induced voltage is according to a left-hand rule.

The induced voltage then creates a current based on Ohm's law $I = G\mathcal{E}$ where $G$ is the conductivity of the wire.

So finally the question about the 'the atomic level' is reduced to a question of how normal laws of electric circuits work 'on the atomic level'.  Ohm's law is explained by solid-state physics which is based on quantum mechanics.  I'm not sure how quantum electrodynamics explains the induction itself or Ohm's law.

Comment: I think the question "how" perfectly fits here. The question is "how" not "why", how the emf is induced in simple words "potential difference" in changing magnetic flux. can't we explain it with magnetic or electric field behaviors. not going in quantum, just from the puss pull behaviours of charges due to either magnetic field or electric field

Answer (score 0):

It is actually not the changing magnetic field
$\mathbf{B}$ directly, which generates the current.

According to [Faraday's law of induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction#Maxwell%E2%80%93Faraday_equation)
$$\nabla\times\mathbf{E} = -\frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial t}
\quad\text{(differential version of the law)}$$
or
$$\oint_{\partial\Sigma}\mathbf{E}\cdot d\mathbf{l}
 =-\int_{\Sigma}{\frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial t}\cdot d\mathbf{A}}
 \quad\text{(integral version of the law)}$$

a changing magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$ is necessarily
accompanied by a curling electric field $\mathbf{E}$.
And it is this electric field $\mathbf{E}$ which
acts on the charges, makes them moving, and thus creates
an electric current.

From the formula above you see,
induction occurs only if $\frac{\partial\mathbf{B}}{\partial t}\ne\mathbf{0}$,
i.e. the magnetic field is changing with time $t$.
For a magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$ constant with time,
no induction occurs.

Comment: hmm ok , this feels interesting, I want to learn more about it how it happens where can I learn more about it in detail or get an explanation. I'm not in university

Comment: @Farhan You can use any introductory text-book or video-lecture on electrodynamics,
like for example the [Feynman lectures](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/) (Volume II).